# Finding alt text on Instagram pic in source code

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, instagram, web-inspector

I'm trying to watch the alternative text on instagram image, let's say for example this one : [Instagram Pic](https://www.instagram.com/p/B-pUJ-aAIfl/)

With chrome, i'm using right click, inspect, but i'm not able to see the alt text in the source code.

However, I know that sometimes, when pic is loading, I can see it.

Really strange.

- Is the alt-text always on Instagram Pics ? If yes, where can I find
- it (id ? class ?) in the source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the alt text in the `FFVAD` class , on the image tag 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, doest that means there are not always alt texts ? for example : https://www.instagram.com/p/B-paCUrCP1X/

Comment: yep not always !